# How to read value of #text from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, dom

Below is the structure:

[image]

How can I read the value of "#text" highlighted in above pic?

Expected: I should get "ACCOUNT_NUMBER" as seen as value after reading.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to get it out of there?

Comment: We'd need to see the constructor for the column object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that property name is real, you need to use string literal syntax, since `column.name.#text` isn't legal syntax with that # sign there.

```
var name = column.name['#text'];
```